# Need to rewrite URL in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I am using wordpress in a subfolder of main domain

```
Ex. domain.tld/sub
```

I have a blog(post) in this wordpress installation
That is domain.tld/sub/blog will give me listing page
and domain.tld/sub/blog/this-is-a-blog will give me a blog detail page

I am using POST for showing this. Now i need to rewrite the URL so that from
Current URL Structure

```
domain.tld/sub/blog will become
domain.tld/blog
```

and all individual blog post should become

```
domain.tld/sub/blog/this-is-a-blog 
TO
domain.tld/blog/this-is-a-blog
```

I tried below code but not working

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule   ^blog/(.+)$   sub/blog/$1   [L]
```

My HTACCESS

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /bim/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule   ^blog/(.+)$   bim/blog/$1   [L]
RewriteRule . /bim/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: https://hostpapasupport.com/move-wordpress-subdomain-root-domain/

Comment: To clarify, you wish to still keep the physical `/sub` subdirectory, but wish to remove this from the URL? Have you already changed the URL structure in WordPress itself to remove `/sub` from the URL?

Comment: @MrWhite Thats correct WP installed on sub folder and my requirement is to rewrite sub/blog/* to blog/*  I do not want to change other WP urls

Comment: Have you removed the `/sub` from the URL in WordPress itself?